# Play framework : How to make dynamic route in form

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.1, actionform

I created a form with play framework but when I want to set the "action" form property like this :

```
    @helper.form(action = @action) {
```

It didn't work ...

My @action is define as a String

How to make this "action" form property dynamic ?

I can do this with "if" but it's ugly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form()` helper expects a `play.api.mvc.Call` as an action, so you need to prepare it somehow, ie in controller, like this:

```
public static Result newForm(String arg1, String arg2) {
    play.api.mvc.Call saveAction = routes.Application.saveForm(arg1, arg2);
    return ok(newFormView.render(saveAction));
}
```

and then just pass `saveAction` into first argument of `form` helper:

```
@(saveAction: play.api.mvc.Call)

@helper.form(saveAction){
   @* form fields *@
}
```